# How to increase max_user_watchers in AWS code build? Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, aws-codebuild, testcasesource

getting this error while starting server to test cypress tests in AWS code build

```
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached
```

so i tried to increase `max_user_watches` to 524288. But then I was getting

```
Running command echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sysctl: setting key "fs.inotify.max_user_watches", ignoring: Read-only file system
```

How could i increase the max user watches in AWS code build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build spec running command on top of all, solved the issue

```
phases:
   install:
      commands:
         - echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sysctl -p
```